# How to use nested accordions using Handorgel library?

Tags: javascript

While using Nested accordions like the below using Handorgel library:

---accordion A

> --accordion A.1
> --accordion A.2
> --accordion A.3

--accordion B

> --accordion B.1
> --accordion B.2

I am trying to open accordion A.1 after opening accordion A i.e the parent accordion. The height of the **content** of accordion A "the parent accordion" is not getting recalculated.

Resulting the content of Accordion A.1 to overflow out of the accordion A content's allocated height. Which is breaking the view.

So the question is:
**Is it feasible to nest the accordions using Handorgel library?**

- If Yes: How to solve this issue?

https://github.com/oncode/handorgel/issues/35